# R: ggmap with "mapdist" function flipping output distances

Tags: r, google-maps-api-3, ggmap

Below is a reproducible example, but you will need a google API to help.  Here is a quick example of the behavior I am seeing.

Given the following code:

```
test.1 <- data.frame(rbind("02908", "98144"), c("60612", "60612"),
                     stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
colnames(test.1) <- c("from", "to")
library(ggmap)
Distance <- mapdist(from = test.1$from,
                       to = test.1$to,
                       mode = "driving",
                       output = "simple")
Distance
```

Yields the following output:

```
> Distance
# A tibble: 2 x 9
  from  to          m    km miles seconds minutes hours mode   
  <chr> <chr>   <int> <dbl> <dbl>   <int>   <dbl> <dbl> <chr>  
1 02908 60612 3321774 3322. 2064.  109087   1818.  30.3 driving
2 98144 60612 1562693 1563.  971.   53819    897.  14.9 driving
```

But when I manually do a search, using the following:

```
mapdist(from = "02908",
        to   = "60612",
        mode = "driving",
        output = "simple")

mapdist(from = "98144",
        to   = "60612",
        mode = "driving",
        output = "simple")
```

I get the following output for each:

```
# A tibble: 1 x 9
  from  to          m    km miles seconds minutes hours mode   
  <chr> <chr>   <int> <dbl> <dbl>   <int>   <dbl> <dbl> <chr>  
1 02908 60612 1562693 1563.  971.   53819    897.  14.9 driving
```

and

```
# A tibble: 1 x 9
  from  to          m    km miles seconds minutes hours mode   
  <chr> <chr>   <int> <dbl> <dbl>   <int>   <dbl> <dbl> <chr>  
1 98144 60612 3321774 3322. 2064.  109087   1818.  30.3 driving
```

As you can see, when I make the call for each "from/to" separately, it's exactly flipped from when I make the call from a dataframe.  Or, more to the point, the distance from "02908" to "60612" = 971 miles when I make the request directly, but 2064 miles when the call comes from a dataframe.  Worse, it appears the individual call is correct, but the call from the dataframe is wrong.  And of course I want to do this for a lot of "from/to" pairs.

Any help would be ever so much appreciated.

Comment: I think there is a bug in the function's code.  If you look at the urls being generated, they are in alphabetical order which does not match the original order of the data frame.  I suggest you report this on the GitHub site.

Comment: This an [open issue on github](https://github.com/dkahle/ggmap/issues/280). I was not able to reproduce this problem at my end (it gives the correct results with your code) - just in case, I am currently using the latest installation of `ggmap` (`3.0.0.901 2020-02-08`)

Comment: Thank you both!   I am using "ggmap 3.0.0. off CRAN.  I'll check the latest version off github.  I now see the open issue so will drop a note there.  In the interim, similar to a solution posted on Github, I did run the function across each line in the dataframe through a loop.  I'll post that solution for anyone looking as, although clunky, it does work as expected..

Comment: @dr_canak, If you reverse sort the data.frame prior to calling the `mapdist` function it should work. `test.1<-test.1[order(test.1$from, decreasing = TRUE),]`

Comment: @Dave2e, Thx!  Interestingly, the data I had was entirely unsorted, but I had sorted it "ascending" to make it easier to spot check some things before grabbing the distances.  Any reason you know of that the call works with data sorted in descending order, rather than ascending?

Comment: If you type "mapdist" you can view the function's script.  The function uses the `split()` function (this sorts the list into ascending order) in preparation for creating the URL's.  Then at end of the script there is a multi line function that converts the variable "out" into the summarized data.frame output, for some reason there is a `rev()` inserted.

Answer (score 0):

Many thx to Ben.  I now see the open issue.  In in the interim, similar to what I found in the issues in Github, I looped the function across each row of the dataframe and stitched the list back into a dateframe. Although clunky, it does seem to give the expected results.

```
test.Distance = apply(test.1,
                      1,
                      function(l) {mapdist(from = l[1],
                                           to = l[2])})


test.Distance <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(test.Distance),
                                   nrow = length(test.Distance),
                                   byrow = T))
colnames(test.Distance) <- c("from", "to", "m", "km", "miles", "seconds",
                             "minutes", "hours", "mode")
```

```
> test.Distance
   from    to       m       km        miles seconds          minutes            hours    mode
1 02908 60612 1562693 1562.693  971.0574302   53819 896.983333333333 14.9497222222222 driving
2 98144 60612 3321774 3321.774 2064.1503636  109087 1818.11666666667 30.3019444444444 driving
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code from the function `mapdist` there is an inconsistence in the code.  The bug is confined to these couple of lines of code.
A side effect from the `split` function results is to sort the "out" dataframe in order of the "from" column, which is different from original data.
Then the function performs a "rev" reverse sort and makes the calls to Google, but the statement never updates the arrangement of the "from_to_df" dataframe, thus producing the inconsistent results.

```
   #from the mapdist function:
   out <- split(from_to_df, from_to_df$from) %>% map(~getdists(.x))

   if (output == "all") 
        return(out)
    out %>% rev() %>% map(function(origin) {
        origin %>% map(~tibble(m = .x$distance$value, km = .x$distance$value/1000, 
            miles = 0.0006214 * .x$distance$value, seconds = .x$duration$value, 
            minutes = .x$duration$value/60, hours = .x$duration$value/3600))
    }) %>% flatten() %>% bind_rows() %>% bind_cols(from_to_df, 
        .) %>% mutate(mode = mode)
```

To cope with the bug in the function's code, an easy fix is to presort the dataframe prior to calling the function and thus avoiding the function's side affect of rearranging the pasted data.

```
test.1 <- bind_rows(split(test.1 , test.1 $from)) %>% arrange(desc(from))
mapdist(test.1$from, test.1$to, mode="driving", output="simple")
```

The first line will split, bind and sort the rows into the proper order for compatibility with the current version of the function.
Or update to the very latest version of ggmap: 3.0.0.901

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue and can confirm that it's now fixed in the development version, 3.0.0.903.

Please try:

`devtools::install_github("dkahle/ggmap")`